# Workaround for Microsoft account 5 PC limit

Tags: windows-store, windows-store-app, microsoft-account

Apparently I can only use my Microsoft account on a maximum of 5 Windows 8 installations before I see the following message:

> You've reached the PC limit for your account

Does anyone have any idea how to increase or eliminate this limit. Obviously I can remove a PC but I would rather not since I do use all 5 at different locations.